# Input an array of char using std::cin.getline() not working reading an integer

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++, char

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    char a[50];
    int y;
    cin >> y;
    cin.getline(a, 40); 
    cout << "y= " << y << "\n"<< "a=" << a << endl;
}
```

When run, I input 45, enter. Then the output is

```
y= 45
a=
```

I haven't have a chance to input `a`. But when I use this code:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    char a[50];
    int y;
    cin.getline(a, 40);
    cin >> y;
    cout << "y= " << y << "\n" << "a=" << a << endl;
}
```

I run it with 45, enter, fish, enter. Its output

```
y= 45
a=fish
```

So, can anybody explain why `cin.getline(a,40)` in first code not work, but it work in second code? I got confused.

Comment: Is it not the case that `cin >> someInt` doesn't eat the newline? Try two `getline()`s and `std::stoi()`. Also, use `std::string` for safety reasons.

Comment: @user3383733 I would just do a `cin.clear();`. It seems more simple to me :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does std::getline() skip input after a formatted extraction?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction)

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, the input will still contain a newline, which is then consumed by the following `cin.getline()` call, which reads to the next newline. 
The program then terminates.

In the second case, `cin.getline()` will read the first line until the newline, and then the first integer after that is being read.

Your problem is therefore that `cin >> y` does not consume your newline character. You can compensate for this by making a second call to `cin.getline()`:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    char a[50];
    int y;
    cin >> y;
    cin.getline(a, 1);
    cin.getline(a, 40); 
    cout << "y= " << y << "\n"<< "a=" << a << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    char a[50];
    int y;
    cin >> y;
    cin.get();
    cin.getline(a, 40); 
    cout << "y= " << y << "\n"<< "a=" << a << endl;
}
```

I found this, it work.
so, just add cin.get() after cin>> y, it will consume \n character.

Thanks everybody have answer my question.